Intel RPL platform notebook has short battery life
When I used a laptop on the RPL platform (i3-1315U) to play video under ubuntu, the power consumption of the whole machine was very high, resulting in a very short battery life. When playing 1080P video through VLC under Windows, the power consumption is about 6.91W, but under ubuntu, through the same test environment and Settings, the power consumption is about 15W, which seriously affects the battery life. I have also tried other intel platforms, the performance is basically the same as the above, I have tried to switch different versions of the kernel, 5.15\6.1\6.5, the problem is still not improved.
Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you very much!
